# Performant comparisons in awk?

Tags: parsing, awk, logparser

I've got a python script that runs through some logs and figured it'd be instructive to do a few benchmarks against some other approaches before deploying this out. When looking at `awk`, I'm hoping to minimize overhead to get a 'fair' shake at beating the somewhat optimized python variant.

My log entries look like:

```
--------
SomeField=SomeValue
OptionallyAppearingField=WhoKnowsWhat
AnotherField=AnotherValue
ExtraStuff=OneBonusKey=1,SecondBonusKey=2,ThirdBonusKey=3,...
--------
```

And I'm keen to get the value of AnotherField when one of our `ThirdBonusKey`s exists and has a certain value (actually just the number 1).

The 'stupid' way here is to set our `RS` to `'--------'` and then just apply a regex to `$0` twice, first to see if `ThirdBonusKey=1` is in the record, and then to extract `AnotherField=(desired_value)`.

But that seems like an unfair comparison, given it's just throwing a regex at the problem (twice!). Without a guaranteed ordering of fields to leverage `awk`'s cool FS skills, is there a quicker or more appropriate approach here? It's possible that the answer is just "this is not a job for `awk`", and that's okay too, I guess.

Cyrus has kindly pointed out that the sketch of code I gave above is not technically code, and he's technically correct, so here's a reasonably stupid implementation:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="--------"} { if ($0 ~ /ThirdBonusKey=1/) { for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if ($i ~ "AnotherField=") { print $i }}}}'
```

Given input

```
--------
SomeField=SomeValue
OptionallyAppearingField=WhoKnowsWhat
AnotherField=DesiredValue1
ExtraStuff=OneBonusKey=1,SecondBonusKey=2,ThirdBonusKey=1,...
--------
SomeField=SomeValue
OptionallyAppearingField=WhoKnowsWhat
AnotherField=DesiredValue2
ExtraStuff=OneBonusKey=1,SecondBonusKey=2,ThirdBonusKey=0,...
--------
SomeField=
ExtraStuff=
--------
```

we'd expect output

```
AnotherField=DesiredValue1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: What you describe seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Huh? Pick up `AnotherField` and `BonusKey` every time you see them. When you encounter `---` print `AnotherField` if you saw the right `BonusKey`, forget everything and continue.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sounds promising

Comment: Your question suggests `ExtraStuff` may precede `AnotherField` but your example implies it doesn't. Which is it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most efficiently I expect:

```
$ awk '/^AnotherField=/{val=$0; next} /[=,]ThirdBonusKey=1(,|$)/{print val}' file
AnotherField=DesiredValue1
```

but more robustly and easier to enhance to do anything else you want later:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[,=[:space:]]"; OFS="=" }
/^-+$/ {
    if ( f["ExtraStuff_ThirdBonusKey"] == 1 ) {
        print "AnotherField", f["AnotherField"]
    }
    delete f
    next
}
{
    if ( $1 == "ExtraStuff" ) {
        pfx = $1
        sub(/[^=]+=/,"")
        f[pfx] = $0
        pfx = pfx "_"
    }
    else {
        pfx = ""
    }
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        f[pfx $i] = $(i+1)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
AnotherField=DesiredValue1
```

That second script first stores all of the values in an array `f[]` so you can access the values by their names, here's what the contents of that array look like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[,=[:space:]]"; OFS="=" }
/^-+$/ {
    for (i in f) printf "> f[%s]=%s\n", i, f[i]
    if ( f["ExtraStuff_ThirdBonusKey"] == 1 ) {
        print "AnotherField", f["AnotherField"]
    }
    print "----"
    delete f
    next
}
{
    if ( $1 == "ExtraStuff" ) {
        pfx = $1
        sub(/[^=]+=/,"")
        f[pfx] = $0
        pfx = pfx "_"
    }
    else {
        pfx = ""
    }
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        f[pfx $i] = $(i+1)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
----
> f[OptionallyAppearingField]=WhoKnowsWhat
> f[AnotherField]=DesiredValue1
> f[ExtraStuff_SecondBonusKey]=2
> f[ExtraStuff_ThirdBonusKey]=1
> f[ExtraStuff_OneBonusKey]=1
> f[SomeField]=SomeValue
> f[ExtraStuff]=OneBonusKey=1,SecondBonusKey=2,ThirdBonusKey=1,...
AnotherField=DesiredValue1
----
> f[OptionallyAppearingField]=WhoKnowsWhat
> f[AnotherField]=DesiredValue2
> f[ExtraStuff_SecondBonusKey]=2
> f[ExtraStuff_ThirdBonusKey]=0
> f[ExtraStuff_OneBonusKey]=1
> f[SomeField]=SomeValue
> f[ExtraStuff]=OneBonusKey=1,SecondBonusKey=2,ThirdBonusKey=0,...
----
> f[SomeField]=
> f[ExtraStuff]=
----
```

Given that you can create whatever conditions and/or print whatever combinations of fields you want in any input or output order.